# Dynamically append Dropzone image upload fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

In my application I have added image upload fields dynamically using `jquery append` 
So I use `dropzone js` and it not work when it append because it not initialize in document load.

So how could I load that dynamically

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){
            $(wrapper).append(
                '<div class="dropzone small-dropzone feedDropZone">' +
                '<div class="dz-message" data-dz-message><p>Drop image or click to select</p></div></div>');
        }
   });
```

Dropzone code is

```
$('#add').on('click', '.feedDropZone', function(){
        // do something here
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

    var minImageWidth = 800, minImageHeight = 600;
        $(this).dropzone({
            url: base_url + "admin/feed/upload",
            maxFiles: 1, 
            maxFilesize: 5,
            acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg",
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            maxfilesexceeded: function (file) {
            },
            createImageThumbnails: true,
            success: function (file, response) {
                imgObject = JSON.parse(response);
            },
            error: function (file, response) {
            },
            init: function () {
                this.on("thumbnail", function (file) {
                    if (file.width < minImageWidth || file.height < minImageHeight) {
                        file.rejectDimensions();
                    }else if(file.size/(1024*1024) > 5){
                        file.rejectFilesize();
                    }
                    else {
                        file.acceptDimensions();
                    }
                });
            }
       });  
});
```

I'm getting below error:

```
Error: No URL provided.
throw new Error("No URL provided.");
```

Comment: where is your base_url variable

Comment: @hsnbl that is defined in header. it is not the issue.

Comment: did you try to remove Dropzone.autoDiscover = false; line

Comment: yes. if it removed another error is shown.